# How to stop an extension hijacking a keydown event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm implementing an IPA keyboard. This is something the user would have to explicity click to turn on, however I noticed in my browser(Brave aka Chrome mod) that an extension I have is hijacking one of the keypress events(Alt+Shift+D), which opens some window for the extension. Is there any way to mark my JS event listener as having priority over the extension?

Currently I'm registering the event listener normally:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", handler, true)
```

Is there a way I can specify that this should have higher priority since it was turned on by the user?

Comment: Don’t think so. But you could let users change the key combination.

Comment: @DennisHackethal It's not really a key combination per se. It's a keyboard, so I have an IPA `ɗ` over the key `D`. Maybe they'll just have to deactivate extensions if they have them.